# How to insert element in Laravel collection after an element with a specified key?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-4

I'm looking to insert an element into a Laravel collection right after another element with a specific key. Something like:

`$collection->get(5)->insertAfter($someElement)`

The order is important because I will be using it to output HTML later in the view. I looked through the API and couldn't find a suitable method. What I'm doing is basically a comments system, and I'm trying to add the comments that are in reply to other comments right after.

Is this doable? I'm using Laravel 4.2. I also am considering doing a lot of splices and merging but that seems like it would be really terrible performance-wise.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If order is sensitive for why you don't use `sortBy` method?

Comment: I would add `parent_id` on comments table, so when user leave a reply to a comment set it as child of the first comment, or you can take a look at this packages: [baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) & [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `->splice()`.
Code will look like this: 
`$collection->splice(5, 0, [$someElement]);`
It will insert `$someElement` into 6th place.

---

**Laravel 5.2 version**

If You need to insert element right after element with `id == 5`, then You have to search for that element and then use found index to insert new element:

```
    $index = $collection->search(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->id == 5;
    });
    $collection->splice($index, 0, [$someElement]);
```

---

**Laravel 4.2 version**

Unfortunately Laravel 4.2 does not accept search parameter as closure, so we have to find index manually:

```
    $foundKey = null;
    foreach ($collection->all() as $key => $item) {
        if ($item->id == 5) {
            $foundKey = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($foundKey !== null)
    {
        $collection->splice($index, 0, [$someElement]);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to do this but $index always came up false. Even when I did:
`
$index = $collection->search(function ($item, $key) {
        return true;
    });
`
I ended up doing something else, where I foreach through the collection and then generated an HTML string for each element and append it to a string variable. Thanks for the help though. Maybe it's because I'm using Laravel 4.2 that $collection->search() didn't work?

Comment: @PhilYu Unfotunately I didn't noticed that You using L4.2. And yes, L4.2 search works a little bit different, it does not accept closures, just raw value [L4.2 search](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L480), [L5.2 search](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L741)